# Rails, RSpec and Factory Girl: how to connect to 2 databases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, testing, rspec

I have a Ruby on Rails app that now has 2 databases, the master one and a secondary one that we'll use only to consume data (other systems here will use it as well, so we must use it exactly this way)

I'm using rspec with factory girl to test the models, but currently I can't test nothing, because appearently rspec can't see the second database.

To make the connection I'm using an abstract class which makes the connection:

```
class PublicoBase < ActiveRecord::Base
    establish_connection "publico_#{Rails.env}"
    self.abstract_class = true
end
```

And I'm getting an error when I run rake spec saying that the database `publico_test` doesn't exists.

This error trows when I try to load the factory girl fixtures, using `FactoryGirl.create :some_model`.

I'm also using 2 schemas to connect to both databases atm.

Someone knows anything that can help me out here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, have a look at [Octopus](https://github.com/tchandy/octopus).

Here is a short decription:

> Octopus supports:
>
> - Sharding (with multiple shards, and
>     grouped shards).
> - Replication
>     (Master/slave support, with multiple
>     slaves).
> - Moving data between shards
>     with migrations.
> - Tools to manage
>     database configurations. (soon)

Comment: Thanks, that would probably work, but my colleagues found another way to fix it: [SecondBase](https://github.com/karledurante/secondbase)